# A mathatical combination problem.

Tags: logic

There are 15 pieces of white chopsticks, 16 pieces of yellow chopsticks and 12 pieces of Brown chopsticks mixed together. Close your eyes. If you want to get one pair of chopsticks that are not white and one pair of chopsticks that are not yellow, at least how many pieces of chopsticks needed to be taken ?

to solve this I took the worst case scenario. First we get 16 pieces of yellow chopsticks and white chopstick and brown chopstick. Then all chopstix a 18 show the next one makes the solution. So my answer is 18. But the real answer that they have given is 6. How to solve this mathematical problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is "at most 19". As you said, In the worst case scenario, you will pick 16 yellow chopsticks, 1 white and 1 brown and will still NOT have 2 pairs. However, the 19th chopstick you pick will be either white or brown, so you will have two pairs guaranteed.

The method used to solve this kind of problems is called [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). There is no fancy math behind it, just logic.

I have absolutely no clue why the "correct" answer would be 6. Perhaps the answer in the book is wrong, or you have misunderstood the question. If you are convinced that the book is right, can you post the EXACT wording of the problem, as stated in the book?

Comment: Thank u Alex for me also it's 19 but IAM sure that I have u the correct wording.

Comment: Can you give more details on where you got the question from?

Comment: this question is taken from Hong Kong international mathematical Olympiad heat round 2018 Senior secondary group 5 th question.